# Transferring values from one database field to another through a php site not working in one instance

Tags: php, mysql

We have a system on our website wherein you can have multiple accounts and earn points on each. Those points you can transfer between the accounts on this webpage that I've noticed an error on. Basically, if I have a certain combination of accounts, namely a first and second, it won't let me transfer, it'll just say "Please fill in with a number.". If I have a first and third or all three, it works fine. I've been looking through it for about two hours now and can't find what isn't working... any help would be IMMENSELY appreciated :D

```
  <?php if($a == "exchange")

  {
  $GetUserInfo = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE id = '$userid'") or die(mysql_error());

    $GetUserInfo = mysql_fetch_object($GetUserInfo);

    $cols = 1; //determines colspan
    $status = 1;

    $GetMultipleInfo = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE id = '".$GetUserInfo->mult_uid."'") or die(mysql_error());  
      if(mysql_num_rows($GetMultipleInfo) != 0)
      {
        ++$cols;
        ++$status;
      }
      $GetMultipleInfo = mysql_fetch_object($GetMultipleInfo);



    $GetAdMultipleInfo = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE id = '".$GetUserInfo->mult_admin."'") or die(mysql_error());
      if(mysql_num_rows($GetAdMultipleInfo) != 0)
      {
        ++$cols;
        $status = ($status == 2 ? 4 : 3);
      }
      $GetAdMultipleInfo = mysql_fetch_object($GetAdMultipleInfo);


// Sparks Transfer
if (isset($_POST['spartrans']))
{
  $order = $_POST['sparrecipients'];

if ($order == 'first')
{
  $tpoints2 = $_POST['tpoints2'];
  $tpoints3 = $_POST['tpoints3'];
  $tpoints = $tpoints2 + $tpoints3;

   if ($status == 2)
      if ((!is_numeric($tpoints1)) || (!is_numeric($tpoints2)) || empty($tpoints1) ||  empty($tpoints2))
        message("Please fill in with a number.","Enchanted Hogwarts","$PHP_SELF?a=exchange");
  elseif ($status == 3)
      if ((!is_numeric($tpoints1)) || (!is_numeric($tpoints3)) || empty($tpoints1) || empty($tpoints3))
        message("Please fill in with a number.","Enchanted Hogwarts","$PHP_SELF?a=exchange");
  elseif ($status == 4)
      if ((!is_numeric($tpoints1)) || (!is_numeric($tpoints2)) || (!is_numeric($tpoints3)) || empty($tpoints1)  ||  empty($tpoints2) || empty($tpoints3))
        message("Please fill in with a number.","Enchanted Hogwarts","$PHP_SELF?a=exchange");

  if ($tpoints2 > $GetMultipleInfo->tpoints)
    message("" . getName($GetMultipleInfo->id) . " does not have enough sparks.","Enchanted Hogwarts","$PHP_SELF?a=exchange");

  if ($tpoints3 > $GetAdMultipleInfo->tpoints)
    message("" . getName($GetAdMultipleInfo->id) . " does not have enough sparks.","Enchanted Hogwarts","$PHP_SELF?a=exchange");

  if ($GetUserInfo->mult_uid != 0)
    mysql_query("UPDATE members SET tpoints = GREATEST(tpoints - $tpoints2,0) WHERE id = '".$GetMultipleInfo->id."'") or die(mysql_error());
  if ($GetUserInfo->mult_admin != 0)
    mysql_query("UPDATE members SET tpoints = GREATEST(tpoints - $tpoints3,0) WHERE id = '".$GetAdMultipleInfo->id."'") or die(mysql_error());
  mysql_query("UPDATE members SET tpoints = GREATEST(tpoints + $tpoints,0) WHERE id = '$userid'") or die(mysql_error());

  message("Successfully transferred $tpoints Sparks to ".getName($userid).".","Enchanted Hogwarts","$PHP_SELF?a=exchange");
}

}

}
?>
```

Comment: *YOU* really need to do a better job narrowing down the problem, you posted nearly 500 lines of code, you expect some one to read all that for you.

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry, I just got quite fed up with it, as much of an excuse as that may be... I've cut it down to as much as I could, I /think/ the problem must be somewhere there...

Comment: Although there are probably several billion examples of PHP with `mysql_query` out there on the web, they're all teaching very bad habits, using an interface from the 1990s that's being retired, and exposing you to very serious [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/php). You should be using `mysqli` or PDO in all new applications to avoid this. As an additional note, what you're doing here is quite involved. Have you thought about using a PHP framework like [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) or [CodeIgnighter](http://codeigniter.com/) to help organize your application better?

Comment: I tried changing some code to mysqli and the page suddenly didn't show... so I'm not sure what I did wrong there. Also this code is a couple of years old, I just never noticed the error because the part where it appears doesn't apply to me.

Answer (score 0):

In your code here you are establishing a couple of variables.

```
if ($order == 'first')
{
    $tpoints2 = $_POST['tpoints2'];
    $tpoints3 = $_POST['tpoints3'];
    $tpoints = $tpoints2 + $tpoints3;
```

But then here you are checking the values of different variables.  **$tpoints1** was never established.

```
if ((!is_numeric($tpoints1)) || (!is_numeric($tpoints2)) || empty($tpoints1) ||  empty($tpoints2))
          message("Please fill in with a number.","Enchanted Hogwarts","$PHP_SELF?a=exchange");
```

EDIT: That is probably not correct.  You probably have register_globals on which would be setting that variable automatically.  Not recommended but not the question you asked.

Bottom line you need to figure out which branch of your code is being executed.  My guess based on your description is that it is the **$order == first** branch and then **$status == 3**.  But without actually submitting the form and knowing which selections were made it is impossible for me to tell.  And the fact that all the error messages are the same "Please fill in with a number." is not very helpful.

I personally would take this time to refactor some of your code.  If I don't understand something I break it apart into smaller chunks until I do.  Otherwise you will always be sifting through this page every time something is wrong trying to figure it out.

Every selection of $order validates the values of $tpoints1, $tpoints2, and $tpoints3 exactly the same way.  Start by moving that into a function and go from there.

Comment: I tried establishing dazzles1 but it didn't change anything :/ And thing is, in the other instance where it is used, it works fine, it's literally just this part, which has the same code as the other one which works, apart from the fact that it's dazzles2 instead of dazzles3. Also, I changed the error message to test which part it was in, and 0 apparently registers as an empty value. Thing is, 0 works in all other parts of the code.

Comment: That is correct. 0 is an empty value according to the PHP docs.  Keep in mind that you are using strings here, so "0" will be empty, "0.0" is not empty.